# Primeng DialogService prevent half pixel

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have the Problem, that when I open use the Dialog Service from primeng with a height in percent all labels in the angular material controls are blurry

[image]

When I set the height to a fix pixel value the label text is clear.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem!

When creating the Dialog with the dialogService you are able to set the height of the Dialog =>

const ref = this.dialogService.open(componentType, { header: this.translation.translate(header), data: data, width: width, **height: height**, styleClass: "background" });

This is not good, it is better when the content of the dialog has a height like "calc(100% - 250px)" than all labels will show in the correct way